# MySQL if Execution Exists

Tags: mysql, sql

i try to set an Existence when there is a data found in my table(user). In the query, i need to use a variable. However, in the `IF` case, it doesn't work. Any ideal? or any alternative way to do it?

```
DECLARE
@myTableName varchar(1000), 
@myQuery varchar(1000)

SET @myTableName = userTable   //the userTable i will retrieve from a parameter
SET @myQuery = 'SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM  ' + @myTableName + ''


IF EXISTS (EXEC(@myQuery))
    BEGIN
        print('Success')
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        print('Failed')
    END
```

Comment: The `sql-server` tag refers a specific database engine that is not compatible with mysql. Don't use those tags together.

Comment: Also, the `TOP 1` syntax is Sql Server specific. MySql would use `LIMIT 1` at the end of the statement instead. So which is it? Are you using Sql Server or MySql?

Answer (score 1):

```
SET @myQuery = 'SELECT * FROM  ' + @myTableName + ' LIMIT 0,1 '
```

If it doesn't work, you can try this approach :

```
DECLARE
@myTableName varchar(1000), 
@i int

SET @myTableName = userTable   //the userTable i will retrieve from a parameter
SET @i = 'SELECT count(*) AS cnt FROM  ' + @myTableName + ''

IF @i > 0
    BEGIN
        print('Success')
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        print('Failed')
    END
```